# how can I start software after installed silently using PowerShell?

Tags: windows, powershell

I have installed software using powershell command, for example 7zip:

```
 Start-Process msiexec -ArgumentList '/I C:\Desktop\7z2106-x64.msi /quiet /passive /L*V "C:\Desktop\package.log"'  -Wait -NoNewWindow
```

And then there are two problems:

1. How to check whether the software is successfully installed?
2. If installed successfully, How to start the software?

I need to solve the two problems with scripts instead of interactive interfaces. I haven't found a good solution. Can anyone help me? Thanks.

Comment: You will only know if the software was installed successfully if that software reports that it does or you can start it normally. So, your two points can be on in the same, for if your software does not report back on the success the option 2 is the only way to validate.

Comment: thanks for your reply. In order to start the software, it seems I need to find the location of the executable executable file. So, how can I get the name or location of the executable file?

Comment: That's quite unpredictable, isnt't it? What if your software consists of more than one executable?

Comment: what about the simple scenario? the software is packaged with windows installer, and there is only one executable file?

Comment: Determine success by checking exit code of `msiexec`. Query install location from the registry key of the software (possibly `HKLM\Software\7-zip`) or from the [uninstall registry key](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/msi/uninstall-registry-key) (value `InstallLocation`). This won't work for unknown software, in which case you would have to use heuristic approach, e. g. looking for shortcuts (*.lnk) created by the installer.

Comment: You can start the program by using powershell `Start-Process` and the path of the installation file/exe. For example in order to start 7zGUI you could use `Start-Process "C:\Program Files\7-Zip\7zFM.exe"`

Comment: Thanks very much. I check the exit code of msiexec, and it works. I Query the uninstall registry key of 7zip, but the InstallLocation is null. I don't know why.

Comment: @GeralexGR how can I get the path of the installation file/exe?

Comment: @jiligulu you could hard code it manually if you know the architecture and program you will install. For example 7-zip 64 bit can be found under the location `C:\Program Files\7-Zip\` . If you want to do that with powershell and automatically get the install folder, then you should go an alternative approach.

Comment: @GeralexGR yes, I'd like to find a more general way to get the install folder. 7-zip is just one example. Is there any way to get the install folder automatically?

Comment: For a general approach it could be tricky as not all software store the installation dir on registry, or they store it on different locations. You could search recursively with a powershell on Program files, and Appdata for the program name but it would require coding and testing.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/240201/discussion-between-jiligulu-and-geralexgr).